# JTree Not Refreshed When Called on Different Location But On Same Event-Dispatching Thread

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have been struggling with `JTree`. I cannot refresh it after I add a new tree node (`DefaultMutableTreeNode`). I am able to refresh it when the code that adds the tree node is *called* from within the GUI class, but not outside it. Here is the code that actually adds the node to the `JTree`:

```
public class TreeViewer extends JPanel implements TreeSelectionListener {
    JTree tree;
    DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode;
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel;

    public void modifyJTree(String name) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(name);
        treeModel.insertNodeInto(childNode, rootNode, rootNode.getChildCount());
    }
}
```

When it is called in the main method, the GUI failed to refresh itself after the node is added. I experimented several ways to put it on the Event-Dispatching Thread, but it does not work. I also tried it on the main thread, and it also failed. The code examples are provided below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final TreeViewer viewer = new CaseViewer();

    // I omit the code that sets up the GUI and displays it

    // This calls modifyJTree on the Event-Dispatching Thread
    // And it does not work     
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        viewer.modifyJTree("InvokeLater");
        }
    });

    // This also calls modifyJTree on the Event-Dispatching Thread
    // And it still does not work       
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
        viewer.modifyJTree("InvokeLater");
        }
    });

    // Using a SwingWorker. Still no luck.
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
    }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            viewer.modifyJTree("SwingerWorker");
        }
    };

    // Now I tried to call it on the main thread, but this cannot work
    viewer.modifyJTree("main thread");
}
```

However, if the call is from within the class, it works. For example, in the constructor of my `TreeViewer` class, as shown below:

```
public TreeViewer() {
    rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root Node");

    treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(rootNode);
    treeModel.addTreeModelListener(new MyTreeModelListener());
    tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    tree.setEditable(false);
    tree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(
    TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);
    tree.setShowsRootHandles(true);
    // Listen for when the selection changes.
    tree.addTreeSelectionListener(this);
    // omitting other initialization stuff

    // Using a SwingWorker. It is the same SwingWorker, but this one works!
    SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            viewer.modifyJTree("InsideSwingerWorker");
        }
    };
}
```

So my impression is that the call must be coming from inside the `TreeViewer` class. However, if the method cannot be called from outside the class, my `TreeViewer` is basically useless.
I can't help but suspect this is a bug of `JVM`. Or am I ignorant of some best practices regarding `JTree`s that caused this weird error?

*Update*: Problem solved. It actually has nothing to do with JTrees. The JTree instance I was modifying was not correctly added into the GUI that I was looking at.

Comment: Make your update an answer, and then accept it. Too bad you're fail.

Answer (score 4):

**Settle down**. First, if you haven't already, read the [How to Use Trees](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html) tutorial. Once you feel comfortable with the material, you can focus your attention on the [Dynamically Changing a Tree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html#dynamic) partition. Therein you'll find sample code that will hopefully make things a little bit more clear for you.

But remember, you're absolutely right in what you're trying to do. That is, respect Swing's single-thread model. Using mechanisms, such as `SwingUtilities` and `SwingWorker` to modify a Swing component when in another thread is absolutely correct, although this does not seem to be applicable in your case. I think you're just a little misguided, or overwhelmed.

Comment: +1 for calm. `JTree` is especially sensitive to correct use of the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).